# Method returning promise is not fully executed despite using await keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm new to JavaScript and actively learning. I am calling a method that returns a promise from within an async method of a ES2016 class, using the await keyword:

```
        export default class MyClass extends Model {
            async getReport() {
                const value = await xlsx.save(await this._getReportFileName());
                console.log('await keyword returned method value');
                console.log(`The value is: ${value}`);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Can anyone spot the reason why the method executes before it has a chance to execute its logic and before resolve is called. The await keyword does not seem to wait for the promise to actually be returned, and the value being output to console is aways undefined.

Object xlsx is an instance of class File that has a method save:

```
export default class File {
    save(filename, options) {
        writer.save(this, filename, options);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for save helper method being called:

```
function save(xlsx, filename, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename, options);
            const zip = archiver('zip');

            stream.on('close', () => {
                console.log('Resolving promise');
                resolve();
            });

            stream.on('error', (err) => {
                console.log('Rejecting promise');
                reject(err);
            });

            zip.pipe(stream);

            const file1 = 'fixtures/file1.txt';
            const file2 = 'fixtures/file2.txt';

            zip
                .append(fs.createReadStream(file1), {
                    name: 'file1.txt'
                })
                .append(fs.createReadStream(file2), {
                    name: 'file2.txt'
                })
                .finalize();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error when saving');
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Could it be that resolve() is not even accessible/available in the scope of listening on the stream event? If so, how can one resolve a promise properly while listening on a stream event?

Comment: Can You show how you call it with **await keyword**?

Comment: Is it not because you put a white space between = and > in your arrow functions ? When I try to declare an arrow function with a white space I got errors

Comment: @Molda, here is how I call the method:
    await xlsx.save(await this._getReportFileName());
    return true;

Comment: @Soywod, you have really good eyes! Could have been an easy fix, however, the white space happened as a result of copy and paste when posting my question. I fixed the code in the question. My actual code contains no space. Any other suggestions about scope of where I call resolve and reject?

Comment: So if you do var x = save(); console.log(x); That should return a Promise object. Are you saying that isn't what you're seeing?

Comment: `await` returns the value of a promise, not the promise itself (presuming you're inside an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). That is it's whole point. You get `undefined` because you call `resolve()` without a value.

Comment: @jib, you are correct, getting undefined is to be expected as there is no value being returned. I just don't understand why the await keyword is not waiting for the promise to resolve. I have completely re-worded my question to better explain the mystery.

Comment: @EugeneV: Can you explain what behavior you're seeing which makes you think that `await` is not waiting for the promise to resolve? Your code has a bunch of log statements in it: can you share what you're actually seeing get logged to the console?

Comment: Also, somethings seems fishy about the way you're calling `xlsx.save([fileName])`, but the method signature you included looks like `save(xlsx, filename, options)`. How is that mapping?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, you got it!!!! I edited my question to include more code. I completely ignored the fact that the save method that was being called was a method of a custom object that in turn called the helper method. Only the helper method was async, but not the object's method. All that time, I was using the await keyword to resolve a method that was not async, silly me!!!! If you want to earn point, point out the issue and I will accept it as correct answer. Thank you so much!!! You can't image how much time I spent looking for a solution.

Comment: Btw, that `try`/`catch` is superfluous, synchronous exceptions are already caught by the promise constructor.

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, thank you, will get rid of the `try/catch` block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `save(filename, options)` pass-through method is not asynchronous, and it's not returning the promise from the `save(xlsx, filename, options)` method.

Try this:

```
export default class File {
    async save(filename, options) {
        await writer.save(this, filename, options);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
export default class File {
    save(filename, options) {
        return writer.save(this, filename, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first doesn't work either to get the `value` variable, you need the `return`. One could use `return await`, but that's pointless.

Comment: @Bergi: As it stands, the `writer.save()` method's Promise will never resolve with a value, so the effect would be the same (i.e. `undefined`). But you're right: if it was modified to resolve a value after `zip.finalize()` completed, then you'd need to `return await`.